# What .NET version is included in XP?

Tags: windows-xp, .net-framework

What about sp2, sp3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[What version of the .NET Framework is included in what version of the OS?](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1.1 might come with sp2. installing the updates versions isn't very hard.

check this out for 2.0 http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0856EACB-4362-4B0D-8EDD-AAB15C5E04F5&displaylang=en